# Ext JS 4.1 get column index in itemcontextmenu

Tags: extjs4.1

When I add listener for itemcontextmenu for Grid/Tree I'm able to access view record, item, index, but how to get column?

What I want to create is a contextMenu but only if user click on items in first column.

Here is my listener function:

```
firstColumnContext: function(view,record,item,index,e,eOpts) {
        console.log(view);
        console.log(record.getName());//this works
        console.log(index);
        console.log('get column');//
},
```

My concept looks like this:

```
firstColumnContext: function(view,record,item,index,e,eOpts) {
        e.stopEvent();
        if(record.get('leaf') && 'first column')
        {
                //show context menu here
        }
},
```

But as I wrote before I need to verify if rightclick was in first column.

Comment: what event are you using for this?  Is this supposed to work only on right click like a normal context menu?

Comment: I'm using itemcontextmenu event. I would like to show custom context menu if user click only on first column which holds treecolumn. Standard contextmenu is disabled for whole application, so if user right click on other column he wont see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this code, setup your grids viewConfig like this:

```
viewConfig: {
            listeners:{
                beforecellcontextmenu: function(view, tableCell, columnIndex, record, tableRow, rowIndex){
                    //your menu code here

                },
                itemcontextmenu: function(view,record,item,index,e,eOpts){
                    e.stopEvent();
                }
            }
        }
```

The column index is provided by the beforecellcontextmenu event but not the fired event does not provide the event itself, so you have to use a combination of both events, one to stop the default menu and the other to pop it up in the case you want it to show.

Comment: Sorry but I can't find beforecellcontextmenu in sencha API, there is beforeitemcontextmenu, but it won't help. I'm using Ext JS 4.1 if that changes something

Comment: Yeah, it's not in the api, but it does exist.  Just give it a try, there is no API standard way of doing this.  This is the only way, strickly using the API will not allow you to do what you want.

Comment: I should mention that I only tried this on a regular grid.  It is very complicated to do this on a treegrid.

Comment: I know, that's why I have so many problems :) I'll try to calculate event position, maybe this will work.

Comment: You want it on a treegrid?  I can probably create a solution for that too.  Event positioning is really bad practice unless you can really test it well on all your target browsers.

Comment: I'm using component called 'Ext Scheduler'. The component can be seen here: http://bryntum.com/examples/scheduler-latest/examples/tree/tree.html and package containing this demo is available at: http://bryntum.com/Bryntum-2.x-45d-trial.zip

Comment: I may be able to help you, we use that component too, give me some time though.

Comment: I'll wait as long as it's needed :) The main problem on Ext JS is community, it's still small and there is lack of examples, especially for Ext JS 4, but thanks to users like You Paul it is easier to start for beginners like me :)

Comment: I just tried my example on a treegrid and it works, what version of Extjs are you using?  I tried it on 4.1.  What part about it exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: Also using Ext 4.1. in my application I'm hiding default context menu, then in schedulerTree (Ext Scheduler 2.1.3) I have context menu for events using 'eventcontextmenu' event. So that only context is shown for events. Next when I add 'beforecellcontextmenu' and try to call simple alert or console log I don't get anything.

Comment: Oh, I forgot you were using scheduler, too many things going on here.

Comment: No problem :) Right now I have context menu for whole row, but it will be nice to have that only in first column.

Comment: Sorry, just too busy right now, this would take a little time for me to figure out, and I just don't seem to be getting that time.

Comment: No problem :) If You'll find some time in future, anyway thanks for help and intentions. I'll try to solve it by my self, it I'll be successful I'll post my solution.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I was wondering if this can be done. You wrote that You are using Scheduler, so maybe these feature was used in Your company before :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. Here is the hack I devised for Grids that works nicely. It compares the mouse position at click to the positions of each column and finds when they overlap.

```
grid.on('itemcontextmenu', function(view, record, item, index, e) {

    var xPos = e.getXY()[0];
    var cols = view.getGridColumns();

    for(var c in cols) {

        var leftEdge = cols[c].getPosition()[0];
        var rightEdge = cols[c].getSize().width + leftEdge;

        if(xPos>=leftEdge && xPos<=rightEdge) {
            console.log(cols[c].dataIndex);
        }
    }
});
```